# Dateadd() like alternative in Visual Fox pro

Tags: visual-foxpro

How can I add year to Date.
I want to add 65 year to date (12\11\1952).
I have tried "12\11\1952" + 65 ,but it is not giving the required value i.e.
12\11\2017.
please suggest how can i achieve this.

Comment: when adding a value to a date, you need to 1st parse the string value to a date object and then call the addYear / addMonth / addDay methods. Adding a string and a number will do an error

Comment: @NitinSingh, I have integer value i.e.  A=65 and date {12\11\1952} when i add  A+ date, it gives {16\01\1953}.could you please suggest what should i do in VFP.

Comment: Thanks @CetinBasoz your below code is working.

Answer (score 3):

When you add an integer to a Date, you are adding **days**. ie: Date(1952,11,12)+65 adds 65 days to Nov 12th, 1952. 
If you add an integer to a DateTime then you are adding **seconds**. ie: datetime() + 60*60 adds an hour (60 seconds * 60 mins) to now.

To add a year to a date in VFP, you use GoMonth(). To Add 65 years you use 65 * 12 months:

```
yearsAdded = GoMonth( Date(1952, 11, 12), 12 * 65 )
```

Comment: @AnkitGupta, it would be helpful to mark this as the answer.